# Hadoop attempt jvm hang up

Tags: hadoop, jvm, freeze

Hadoop 0.20.2

There are a couple of jobs need to be executed one by one, and some attempt job's JVM can't be killed. Logs below. It seems like the tasktracker can't find the JVMId if you see "**JVM Not killed jvm_201208192339_6873_m_1286217329 but just removed**". I have seen the source code. But I can't find out the reason why the tasktracker can't find the JVMId. By the way, there are 13 tasktrakers, and only the new 3 of them got this problem, did I forget to configure something? 
Somebody help me find the reason? Thanks. ^O^

> 2012-09-20 13:52:56,655 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskTracker:
>   Received KillTaskAction for task: attempt_201208192339_6873_m_004334_0
>
> 2012-09-20 13:52:56,655 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskTracker:
>   About to purge task: attempt_201208192339_6873_m_004334_0
>
> 2012-09-20 13:52:56,655 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JvmManager:
>   **JVM Not killed jvm_201208192339_6873_m_1286217329 but just removed**
>
> 2012-09-20 13:52:56,655 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskTracker:
>   addFreeSlot : current free slots : 8
>
> 2012-09-20 13:52:56,655 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapred.IndexCache: Map
>   ID attempt_201208192339_6873_m_004334_0 not found in cache
>
> 2012-09-20 13:52:56,962 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskTracker:
>   LaunchTaskAction (registerTask): attempt_201208192339_6873_m_004334_0
>   task's state:KILLED_UNCLEAN
>
> 2012-09-20 13:52:56,962 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskTracker:
>   Trying to launch : attempt_201208192339_6873_m_004334_0 which needs 1
>   slots
>
> 2012-09-20 13:52:56,962 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskTracker: In
>   TaskLauncher, current free slots : 8 and trying to launch
>   attempt_201208192339_6873_m_004334_0 which needs 1 slots
>
> 2012-09-20 13:52:56,968 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JvmManager: In
>   JvmRunner constructed JVM ID: jvm_201208192339_6873_m_677724590
>
> 2012-09-20 13:52:56,968 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JvmManager: JVM
>   Runner jvm_201208192339_6873_m_677724590 spawned.
>
> 2012-09-20 13:52:56,974 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskController:
>   Writing commands to
>   /disk10/hdfs/mapred/local/ttprivate/taskTracker/root/jobcache/job_201208192339_6873/attempt_201208192339_6873_m_004334_0.cleanup/taskjvm.sh
>
> 2012-09-20 13:52:58,017 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskTracker: JVM
>   with ID: jvm_201208192339_6873_m_677724590 given task:
>   attempt_201208192339_6873_m_004334_0
>
> 2012-09-20 13:52:58,557 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskTracker:
>   attempt_201208192339_6873_m_004334_0 0.0%
>
> 2012-09-20 13:52:58,564 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskTracker:
>   attempt_201208192339_6873_m_004334_0 0.0% cleanup
>
> 2012-09-20 13:52:58,566 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskTracker:
>   Task attempt_201208192339_6873_m_004334_0 is done.
>
> 2012-09-20 13:52:58,566 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskTracker:
>   reported output size for attempt_201208192339_6873_m_004334_0  was -1
>
> 2012-09-20 13:52:58,566 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskTracker:
>   addFreeSlot : current free slots : 8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eventually, that node with this problem has another issue that is its operating system didn't match the hardware.After running job in new operating system for a while, that problem didn't appear again. The old operating system turned out to not perform well in network. It will lower the network bandwidth.